# reformat butchered text using linux

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have some text which is formatted as follows:

```
                1   一项庄严肃穆富历史意义的仪式标志中华人民共和国对香港恢复行使主权。
                2   英国皇储威尔斯亲王与中华人民共和国国家主席江泽民均在仪式上致辞，仪式於六月三十日午夜至七月一日凌晨举行，并向全世界直播。
                3   仪式在香港会议展览中心新翼大厅举行，约四千名嘉宾出席，包括来自四十多个国家和国际性组织的外交部长和知名人士，以及约四百名各国传媒
代表。
```

This is part of a hyper-massive document.

What I would like to do is remove everything before the start of the sentence, i.e. all the whitespace and the line numbers, while leaving the sentences totally intact.

What would be a fast and effective way to do this on linux?

One other challenge is that some lines have been broken apart and moved down to lower lines, this is problematic, ideally I would like to reattach those components to the sentences from whence they came, i.e. the ones directly above them. This is exemplified by the last sentence in the above example.

I guess this could be done with regex or sed but I'm quite unfamiliar with these tools.

Maybe as a preprocessing step there's a command that can take everything with no white space and number in front of it that appears on a new line and appends that to the end of the above line?

Comment: is the whole document with text like this or other element could occur (like any formated document such html, word, ...) and should those lines selected inside ?

Comment: This is one of the files: https://app.box.com/s/zigt9ponvuhw47khrebm6ozbge44no1o

Comment: @user3787253 Oh, that's easy. Just click "Download" on the top-right, then use `iconv -fGB18030 -tUTF-8 < c.input_0.txt > c.input_0.utf-8.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full solution to both issues could be done using Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n//;s/^[\s\d]+/\n/a;' file

一项庄严肃穆富历史意义的仪式标志中华人民共和国对香港恢复行使主权。
英国皇储威尔斯亲王与中华人民共和国国家主席江泽民均在仪式上致辞，仪式於六月三十日午夜至七月一日凌晨举行，并向全世界直播。
仪式在香港会议展览中心新翼大厅举行，约四千名嘉宾出席，包括来自四十多个国家和国际性组织的外交部长和知名人士，以及约四百名各国传媒代表。
```

but with two caveats:

1. A blank line is inserted into the beginning.
2. The final newline is removed.

If you can live with those two limitations, then the solution above will work. The way it works is as follows:

1. First, it remove the newline from the end of the line.
2. Then, if the line begins with a sequence of spaces and digits (the `/a` modifier makes the `\d` and `\s` match ASCII digits and spaces only), replace that with a newline.

Answer (score 3):

You could use sed like below,

```
$ sed 's/^[[:blank:][:digit:]]\+//' file
一项庄严肃穆富历史意义的仪式标志中华人民共和国对香港恢复行使主权。
英国皇储威尔斯亲王与中华人民共和国国家主席江泽民均在仪式上致辞，仪式於六月三十日午夜至七月一日凌晨举行，并向全世界直播。
仪式在香港会议展览中心新翼大厅举行，约四千名嘉宾出席，包括来自四十多个国家和国际性组织的外交部长和知名人士，以及约四百名各国传媒
代表。
```

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[[:blank:][:digit:]]\+` POSIX character class which matches `\+` one or more `[:blank:]` blank spaces or `[:digit:]` digits.
- Replacing those matched characters with an empty string will give you the desired output

Comment: 一 is the Chinese character for one. I wonder if, in the OP's locale, that would match `[:digit:]`.

Comment: then it would be `sed 's/^[[:blank:]0-9]\+//' file`

Comment: schpladow. you're the man, that worked perfectly! But I still need to get those pesky fragments back on the line that they were chopped off from, do you know how I might swing that?

Comment: wait, so use sed 's/^[[:blank:]0-9]\+//' file instead of what you originally posted?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young but wouldn't the chinese character for one and that symbol be encoded differently? wouldn't sed pick up on that?

Comment: @user3787253: The character class `[[:digit:]]` is locale-sensitive and might include characters other than `0-9` as digits.

Comment: Why do people keep up voting that answer? It only responds to part of the question.

Comment: @user3787253: if the 。 character marks the end of the sentence, you can use commands like `sed -e 's/^[[:blank:]0-9]*//' -e ':again' -e '/[^。]$/{ N; s/\n//; t again' -e '}' chinese.txt` as extra processing.  The labels and branches are fussy; you have to have a newline after them, or move to a new `-e` argument, instead of a semicolon.  I've tested that code casually on the sample data.  I've not tested it on more severely split data.  It would be possible to replace the newline and following white space with nothing if that was more appropriate.

Comment: @user3787253 could you elaborate you needs?

Comment: @AvinashRaj It's articulated in the original question. Basically the OP wants to join up the lines that don't start with the number-space sequence.